# Organizing uploads in year/month format

Tags: php

I need a little help. Im a newbie. I'm trying to create a php script for uploading files. Currently I'm using a static/fixed location for uploading. But I want to organize them according to year/ month folders. just like wordpress. here is the code I'm using

```
$config['baseurl']  =  'http://mysite.com';
$config['path'] = $config['basedir'].'/uploads';
```

**currently image path looks like:** http://mysite.com/uploads/image.jpg

**but I want:** http://mysite.com/uploads/2012/07/image.jpg

I'll very appreciate if someone make me a little php code. Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @TomWalters I believe the links were to show a path example, not to point anywhere.

Comment: Oops, time for a coffee I think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the date to the path like this:

```
$config['path'] = $config['basedir'].'/uploads/' . date('Y') . '/' . date('M');
```

You will need to also check that the path exists, and create it if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, will it detect server year/month automatically?

Comment: so you mean, every time I'll have to create folders using ftp? that'd be horrible experience. Thanks for helping. is there anyway to create these folders automatically?

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas you can create the folders automatically using PHP mkdir: http://uk.php.net/mkdir